# Can't figure out why lost parts of the data which were sent from BLE 5 in STM32WB (server) to the client

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, interrupt

I have a problem with data in STM32WB, please give me any advice how I can solve it.
I send data via BLE5 in STM32WB (client) to STM32WB(server). If I send just one byte it is OK. But I need to send data from ADC in real-time in the loop.
Via interrupt (Push button - `CFG_TASK_SW1_BUTTON_PUSHED_ID`) I call the function `P2PS_Send_Notification` in the file p2p_server_app.c

```c
void P2PS_APP_Init(void)
{
    UTIL_SEQ_RegTask( 1<< CFG_TASK_SW1_BUTTON_PUSHED_ID, UTIL_SEQ_RFU, P2PS_Send_Notification );
    return;
}
```

and just for testing, I send data in the next format `4 5 5 5` in the loop (is it ok use loop here ?) with the next code in the function `P2PS_Send_Notification`:

```c
void P2PS_Send_Notification(void)   
{
    int start_data = 4;
    int local  = 5;
    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            P2PS_STM_App_Update_Char(P2P_NOTIFY_CHAR_UUID, (uint8_t *) (&start_data));
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
                P2PS_STM_App_Update_Char(P2P_NOTIFY_CHAR_UUID, (uint8_t *) (&local));
            }
        }
    }
```

But in the server script, I receive `4 5 5 5 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 4 4 5 5 5`
Looks like something interrupt my loop

Comment: Is your characteristic configured as an indication or a notification? Notifications are unacknowledged and sent on a "best try" basis. Indications are acknowledged and will be retried if not acknowledged.

Comment: In my case it is - notification

Comment: Might be worth changing it to an indication and see if the behaviour changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, MCU in server worked faster than MCU in client